# ios - how to embed the UITabBarController inside a UINavigationController and give it 3 tabs?

Tags: ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am finding many existing questions on this issue, but so far they feel a bit more complex that what I need.

I am just trying to understand the basics.  So far what I did is I put a new UIViewController screen into my storyboard. And then I dragged the UITabBar into that new screen.

But I am not sure if that is correct because what I read is there should be a UITabBarController instead of just a UITabBar so this is confusing me.

I also have a NavigationController that is already working so I am also trying to figure out how to embed the NavigationController in the UITabBar or the UITabBarController (which ever I need).

Could anyone please help me understand where I am going wrong here, and what is the correct approach here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to drag in a tab bar, you should use the tab bar controller. Drag a tab bar controller from the objects list, and place it to the left of your navigation controller. Make it the initial controller by selecting it and checking the "Is Initial Scene" box in the inspector. If you don't want the two view controllers that you get automatically with the tab bar controller, you can delete them. You can drag from the tab bar controller to your navigation controller to hook it up, and make it one of the tabs (choose the view controllers option under "Relationship Segue" when you let go).